# How to inject dependencies from IHostedService before creating scope

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, backgroundworker, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a multi tenant system with background job. The tenancy details are stored in database and based on the tenant adding request in service bus, I want to resolve the dependencies based on tenant.

For this I would have to add dependencies to service collection before creating scope. When trying to inject IServiceCollection, it gives me error.

I am looking for the best way to inject dependencies from HostedService

```
public async Task MessageHandler(object sender, Message message)
{
     // Inject dependencies
     services.AddScoped<IMyService,Myservice>(); // No way to get services here
    
     using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
     {
           var ... = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<...>();
           //...
     }
}
```

Comment: With default DI container you can't inject services after it was build.

Comment: Is there any other DI that provides this flexibility?

Comment: Dependent on the case you can just use factory pattern, or look into Autofac for example. Not sure about [others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement).

Comment: How does factory pattern here?

Comment: @Ankit basically you just create a factory which will instantiate what's needed based on the provided parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need a while back.  I created my own service bus handler.

You could try something like the below, where you inject a service (here as an example I'm using IMessageService) to the ServiceeBusHandler that itself has a dbcontext injected.

Then where ever you implement IServiceBusHandler you can specify for which tenant (and their queues) you want the connection built.

```
public class ServiceBusHandler : IServiceBusHandler
{
    private readonly ServiceBusSender _serviceBusSender;
    private readonly IMessageService _messageService;
    
    public ServiceBusHandler(
        ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender,
        IMessageService messageService)
    {
        _serviceBusSender = serviceBusSender;
        _messageService = messageService;
    }

    public async Task PublishMessageAsync<T>(T message)
    {
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        var serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(jsonString);

        await _serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage);
    }

    internal static IServiceBusHandler Create(ServiceBusSender sender)
    {
        return new ServiceBusHandler(sender);
    }
}

public class ServiceBusHandlerFactory : IServiceBusHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient> _serviceBusClientFactory;

    public ServiceBusHandlerFactory(
        IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient> serviceBusClientFactory)
    {
        _serviceBusClientFactory = serviceBusClientFactory;
    }

    public IServiceBusHandler GetClient(string tenantId)
    {
        var tenantDetails = _messageService.GetTenantDetails(tenantId); // Call to your DB to get details about the Tenant      
        var client = GetServiceBusClient(tenantDetails.QueueName);
        var sender = client.CreateSender(tenantDetails.QueueName);
        return ServiceBusHandler.Create(sender);
    }

    protected virtual ServiceBusClient GetServiceBusClient(string queueName)
    {
        var client = _serviceBusClientFactory.CreateClient(queueName);
        return client;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is to change the set of registrations *after* the Container was built. MS.DI does not support this, and while historically, more mature DI Containers tended to support this behavior, most modern DI Containers stopped supporting this, because there are too many negative consequences in allowing this. Autofac, for instance, obsoleted its `Update` method in 2016 and [described the issues with updating the Container in details](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811). Ninject has gone through a similar process, although development stopped before the final release that removed the possibility to update the Container. The Simple Injector DI Container never supported updating, and its [documentation has some clear texts](https://simpleinjector.org/locked) that describe what the issue is.

You might find a DI Container that supports this, but I would urge you to abbondon this path, because of the negative consequences that it can (and probably will) cause, as the previous links described.

Instead, you will have to find a different way to get tenant-specific behavior, with one single set of registrations. The trick here, typically lies in creating a Proxy implementation of your `IMyService` that can forward the call to the correct tenant implementation.

This might look something like this:

```cs
public class ProxyMyService : IMyService
{
    public IMyService Service { get; set; }
    
    // IMyService methods
    public void SomeMethod() => this.Service.SomeMethod();
}
```

This proxy class can be registered at startup, together with other `IMyService` implementations, as follows:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService, ProxyMyService>();

services.AddTransient<MyServiceTenant1>();
services.AddTransient<DefaultMyServiceTenant>();
```

With this, your hosted service can become the following:

```cs
private ProxyMyService service;

public MyHostedService(IMyService service)
{
    this.service = (ProxyMyService)service;
}

public async Task MessageHandler(object sender, Message message)
{
    using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var p = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var proxy = (ProxyMyService)p.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
        proxy.Service = IsTentant1
            ? p.GetRequiredService<MyServiceTenant1>()
            : p.GetRequiredService<DefaultMyServiceTenant>();
    
         var ... = p.GetRequiredService<...>();
         //...
   }
}
```

A more evolved solution would entail a Proxy implementation that allows to switch between tenant-specific implementations internally. That would likely mean moving part of the logic that's currently inside `MessageHandler` into the `ProxyMyService`.

Do notice that the solutions I suggested do not require an abstract factory. Abstract factories are typically [not needed](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/).